# Repository not found

Tags: server, 20.04

I'm getting
`E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.` While running `sudo apt update` in a LTS 20.04 server, I'm currently trying to install python3 but it seems it's not being found either. Not sure what to do. Any assistance?

Comment: This would be a PPA that was recently added, as `hirsute` is 21.04. If you do not need the `deadsnakes` PPA anymore, you can remove it to eliminate this error.

Comment: I have tried following through that link above. It didn't help at all. `sudo do-releases-upgrade` Isn't a command apparently.

Comment: Your system already has Python3. You don't need to install it. Trying to install Hirsute (21.04) packages onto a 20.04 system is unwise: It rarely works. And the duplicate link *explains* what "no Release file" means: It's not a system error to be fixed -- you (the human) made a mistake when you chose that PPA.

Comment: And, for the record, the command is `sudo do-release-upgrade` but this shouldn't be used unless you want to do a release upgrade, obviously.

Comment: Ok I realized I made a mistake, So how the hell do I remove that package then.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - was apparently using 21.04 but didn't realize when I was meant to use 20.04, don't know how the other stuff started.